# Cartesian product of open sets

Tags: general-topology

Say I am dealing with the standard topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R^2}$ and I have the sets $a , b \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $a = (2, 4)$ and $b = (5, 6)$.

Then does it mean that $a \times b \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ and $a \times b = (2, 4) \times (5, 6) = \{ (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x_1 \in (2, 4)$ and $x_2 \in (5,6)\}$?

Comment: "...is open?" is probably missing ;)

Comment: Neither of those sets are open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. They are not even subsets there, and the most natural way to make them so (ie, taking that interval on one axis) would not make them open.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oops, I meant open in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Ok. In that case, yes, that set is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by definition of the product topology, which is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you have not shown this to be the case, however, then you will need to show it directly.

Comment: @DanielRust Cheers, I really need to stop being so sloppy. I always believe that mixing up subset and element of makes a statement just plain wrong, even though generally you can see what people meant.

Answer (score 1):

There are two standard ways to show that the open rectangle is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and they really depend on which definition you use for the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you define the standard topology in terms of a basis of open balls, then showing that each element in the open rectangle has a neighbourhood fully contained in the rectangle is the easiest (just take various minimum radii to find the radius to choose for the ball).

If you define the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in terms of the product topology inherited as the space $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ then you can easily note that the preimage of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ of the projections onto the two copies of $\mathbb{R}$ must be open (these will be two open 'strips' in $\mathbb{R}^2$ - one vertical, one horizontal) because projections are open, and so their intersection (which, being an intersection of these two open strips will give the open rectangle) must also be open.